# Custom Objective Function to optimize Fscore - XGBOOST

Tags: r, xgboost

I am trying to implement `xgboost` on a classification data with imbalanced classes (1% of ones and 99% zeroes).

I am using `binary:logistic` as the objective function for classification.

According to my knowledge on `xgboost` - As the boosting starts building trees, the objective function is optimized iteratively achieving best performance at the end when all the trees are combined.

In my data due to imbalance in the classes, I am facing the problem of [Accuracy Paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Accuracy_paradox). Where at the end of the model I am able to achieve great `accuracy` but **poor** `precision` and `recall`

I wanted a custom objective function that can optimize the model and returns a final xgboost model with best `f-score`. Or can I use any other objective functions that can return in best `f-score` ?

> Where **F-Score** = (2 * Precision * Recall)/(Precision + Recall)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm no expert in the matter, but I think this evaluation metric should do the job:

```
f1score_eval <- function(preds, dtrain) {
  labels <- getinfo(dtrain, "label")

  e_TP <- sum( (labels==1) & (preds >= 0.5) )
  e_FP <- sum( (labels==0) & (preds >= 0.5) )
  e_FN <- sum( (labels==1) & (preds < 0.5) )
  e_TN <- sum( (labels==0) & (preds < 0.5) )

  e_precision <- e_TP / (e_TP+e_FP)
  e_recall <- e_TP / (e_TP+e_FN)

  e_f1 <- 2*(e_precision*e_recall)/(e_precision+e_recall)

  return(list(metric = "f1-score", value = e_f1))
}
```

***References:***

https://github.com/dmlc/xgboost/issues/1152

http://xgboost.readthedocs.io/en/latest/parameter.html

Comment: What I don't understand here is what the preds are?  This is a function that you pass to eval_metric right?  So how do you access the preds from where the model is being calculated?

Comment: Question is for the OBJECTIVE function, not for EVALUATION function